# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter

When I install OpenCV, I get an error as shown below. What should I do?

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

[image: Jupyter error]

Answer (score 0):

### Installing OpenCV

To install a package in Jupyter Notebook, you can use the magic `%pip` command.

```
%pip install opencv-python
```

If the above command doesn't work on `IPython < 7.3`, you can try this command instead.

```
!pip install --user opencv-python
```

---

### Demonstration

Let's see it in action. First, you insert a new cell, type in either of the two commands above, and then execute the cell using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> shortcut.

[image: Installing OpenCV]

You should now be able to import and use OpenCV without any errors.

[image: Importing OpenCV]

Comment: I do not understand. I have tried many ways but it doesn't work. Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: @Trung I have edited the instructions to be more clear and detailed.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it

Comment: @Trung Hello, if my answer helped, could you click the grey checkmark next to my answer to mark it as the solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a dependency issue. Just .pyd is not enough (all .DLLs are required).
On Windows add entries to .dll into PATH environment variable (not enough for Python 3.8 with updated security policies)